# Partition file not creating for new hive table created

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, hive, hiveql

Table created successfully, but partition not created/ partition file is not creating.

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table_name(col1,col2)
    PARTITIONED BY (`biz_dt` date) -- partition created 
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
    WITH SERDEPROPERTIES('quoteChar'='\"','separatorChar'=',')
    STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'                                           
    OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'                   
    LOCATION 'hdfs://path/'  
    TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1','transient_lastDdlTime'='1563368415');
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new table, no files are created. It will create only the folder where to store the file (if not exists) and that's all. 
The files will be created in the moment when you insert data into table.

Also, no partition it's added until you add it (alter table, or dynamically through insert into table).

Hope that this it's helping you.